# Critical value of a function with two variables

Tags: calculus, functions

How do you find the critical value of the two following functions:

$a. f(x,y)=\sin(x+y)$

$b. f(x,y)=\log(1+x^2+y^2)$

I am aware of the fact that I have to differentiate wrt x and y and then let them equal 0, but I kind of get stuck after that. For example for a) I don't know how to solve $\cos(x+y)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For a) we have
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\cos(x+y)$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\cos(x+y)$$
and we get $$\cos(x+y)=0$$ for $$c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left(x=2 \pi  c_1-y-\frac{\pi
   }{2}\lor x=2 \pi  c_1-y+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$

For b) we find only a minimum for $x=0,y=0$

Comment: My bad, I wrote the wrong function, it was the one with sinus :)